# Display all mouseover events in swing?

Tags: java, swing, events, mouseevent

I'm attempting to debug a Java application.  There are several swing events and I'm trying to narrow them down since I don't know quite yet where the bug is coming from.  Is there a way to output all swing events with the handles that caused them to the console?

Comment: Are you using logging? That's where I'd start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to output all swing events with the handles that caused them to the console?

For *debugging* to help find where events are coming from, one can use `AWTEventListeners` to listen to all events that are dispatched.

Simply try with [AWTEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AWTEventListener.html). Add more [AWTEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html) whatever you want to listen for.

```
long eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK
        | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK;

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
        String paramString = e.paramString();
        System.out.println(paramString);
    }
}, eventMask);
```

sample output;

```
MOUSE_MOVED,(131,144),absolute(131,144),clickCount=0
MOUSE_PRESSED,(131,144),absolute(131,144),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1
MOUSE_RELEASED,(131,144),absolute(131,144),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1
MOUSE_CLICKED,(131,144),absolute(131,144),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1
MOUSE_MOVED,(134,143),absolute(134,143),clickCount=0
MOUSE_MOVED,(135,142),absolute(135,142),clickCount=0
MOUSE_MOVED,(172,118),absolute(172,118),clickCount=0
KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=70,keyText=F,keyChar='f',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=70,primaryLevelUnicode=102,scancode=33,extendedKeyCode=0x46
key pressed:70
KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='f',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0
KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=68,keyText=D,keyChar='d',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=68,primaryLevelUnicode=100,scancode=32,extendedKeyCode=0x44
key pressed:68
KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='d',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0
KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=83,keyText=S,keyChar='s',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=83,primaryLevelUnicode=115,scancode=31,extendedKeyCode=0x53
key pressed:83
KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='s',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0
KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=70,keyText=F,keyChar='f',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=70,primaryLevelUnicode=102,scancode=33,extendedKeyCode=0x46
KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=70,keyText=F,keyChar='f',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=70,primaryLevelUnicode=102,scancode=33,extendedKeyCode=0x46
key pressed:70
```